# Infinite Abelian Groups: Unnecessary Hypothesis in Kaplansky's Lemma 7

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, infinite-groups

Looking for a validation of a proof of a stronger statement.  The essential argument that needs review is the final paragraph.  This would obviate the need for a much more complicated argument I gave at [Correcting Proof of Lemma 10 in Kaplansky's *Infinite Abelian Groups*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151491/correcting-proof-of-lemma-10-in-kaplanskys-infinite-abelian-groups) as this version of Lemma 7 would suffice in the proof of Lemma 10.

The lemma states:

> Let $G$ be a primary group and $S$ a subgroup with no elements of infinite height.  Suppose that the elements of order $p$ in $S$ have the same height in $S$ as in $G$.  Then $S$ is pure.

Here "primary group" means "abelian p-group".  The height of $x$ in $G$ (denoted $h_G(x)$) is the supremum of all $n$ such that there exists a $y$ with $x=p^ny$.  $S$ is pure if the height of every element of $S$ is the same in $S$ as it is in $G$.

I claim that the hypothesis that $S$ have no elements of infinite height is unnecessary.  We can state:

Let $G$ be a primary group and $S$ a subgroup.  Suppose that the elements of order $p$ in $S$ have the same height in $S$ as in $G$.  Then $S$ is pure.

Proof (following Kaplansky quite closely, but adding (II)): Induct on the order of $x$.  If it is true that all elements of $S$ of order $p^n$ or less have the same height in $S$ and $G$, let $x$ have order $p^{n+1}$.  Then $px$ has the same height in $S$ and $G$; denote that common height by $r$, which may be $\infty$, and is at least $1$.

(I) If $r<\infty$ then $px=p^ry$ for some $y\in S$.    Then the height of $p^{r-1}y$ must be $r-1$ even in $G$, lest $px$ have height more than $r$.   Note that $x=(x-p^{r-1}y)+p^{r-1}y$. Since $p(x-p^{r-1}y)=0$, $x-p^{r-1}y$ has the same height $k$ in $G$ and in $S$.  If $k\ne r-1$, even if $k=\infty$, then $h(x)=min(k,r-1)$ in both $G$ and $S$.  If $k=r-1$, then $h(x)=r$ in both $S$ and $G$, since it must be at least $r$ as the sum of elements of height $r$, and it must be at most $r$ lest $px$ have height greater than $r$.

(II)  If $r=\infty$ then for any positive integer $m$ there exists a $y\in S$ with $px=p^my$.  The height of $p^{m-1}y$ must be at least $m-1$ in both $G$ and $S$, though it need not be the same in both.  The height of $x-p^{m-1}y$, call it $j$, must be the same in $G$ and $S$ since it has order $p$.  Thus, if $j<m-1$, the height of $x$ must be exactly $j$ in both $G$ and $S$.  And if not, the height of $x$ is at least $m-1$ in $S$.  But if $x$ has finite height $i$ in $S$, we can choose $m>i+1$, and we see that $x$ also has height $i$ in $G$.  On the other hand, if $x$ has infinite height in $S$ it clearly also has infinite height in $G$.